# Javascript function doesn't work on uncheck the check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```js
$('#checkboxF1').on('change', function() {
  alert("test");
});

function check_box() {
  document.getElementById("checkboxF1").checked = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="check_box" onclick="check_box();">check box</button>
<br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxF1" class="css-checkbox">Test
```

The onchange function works when checking the checkbox directly but it doesn't work when checking the checkbox through a function, i.e. the function named `check_box()`.

I want to invoke the onchange function when check the checkbox is check through the function `check_box()`.

Comment: yea. it too works when i directly click the check box. but it doesn't work when i change the checked state via onclick the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is changing the checkbox state does not fires the event.
Try trigger instead.

```js
var chk = $('#checkboxF1');

chk.on('change', function() {
  alert("test");
});

function check_box() {
  chk.trigger('click');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="check_box" onclick="check_box();">check box</button>
<br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxF1" class="css-checkbox">Test
```

Answer (score 3):

This is normal for `input` tags.  When you change the value programmatically, the change event does not fire.  That's just how they are designed.

A usual work-around is to either call the change function directly or trigger the change event manually whenever you change the value programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, try this:

```
function check_box(){
    $("#checkboxF1").prop('checked', true);
}
```

EDIT: I put your function in a snippet, and it works fine too.  It checks the box.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <button id="check_box" onclick="check_box();"> check box </button>
    <br> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxF1" class="css-checkbox"> Test

    <script>
    $('#checkboxF1').on('change', function() {
  alert("test"); 
});

    function check_box(){
        document.getElementById("checkboxF1").checked = true;   
    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

If you are trying to *toggle* the checkbox with the button.  Then do this:

```
function check_box(){
    $("#checkboxF1").prop('checked', !$("#checkboxF1").prop('checked'));
}
```

If this isn't it, then I don't understand the question.

EDIT 2: Ok, if the onchange event doesn't fire; try to force it.

```
$('#checkboxF1').trigger('change');
```

Comment: yea. it too works when i directly click the check box. but it doesn't work when i change the checked state via onclick the button.

Comment: His problem is not that the box doesn't get checked. Its that the `onchange` handler doesn't fire.

Comment: Thanks for translating. Made another edit, though I'm not confident in this.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

// Create a new 'change' event

var event = new Event('change');

// Dispatch it

element.dispatchEvent(event);

let me know if this helps...

Answer (score 0):

See code below.

```js
$('#checkboxF1').on('change', function() {
  alert("test");
});

function check_box() {
  // emulate the checkbox.
  var checkboxF1 = document.getElementById("checkboxF1");
  checkboxF1.checked = !checkboxF1.checked;
  // trigger the onChange event.
  $('#checkboxF1').trigger('change');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="check_box" onclick="check_box();">check box</button>
<br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxF1" class="css-checkbox">Test
```